# Is it possible to train the inputs of deep neural network part by part

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I was wondering if possible to train the inputs of neural network part by part. For example, suppose that I have neural network of inputs 256, and output of 256. what I am asking is about the possibility to take groups  where each group contains only 16 out of 265 of the inputs in order to be predicted based on a single model trained independently and then concatenate the whole groups at final outputs.

For example, the below example is provided :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

x_train = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_train = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

x_test =  [[0.,0.],[.5,.5],[.5,0.],[0.,.5]]
y_test = [[0.],[0.],[2.],[2.]]

# use placeholder instead so you can have different inputs
x = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder('float32',)

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, m1) + b1)
# Layer 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3,1], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
y_out = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, m2) + b2)
### loss
# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - y_out))
# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

# the two feed dictionaries
feeddict_train = {x: x_train, y: y_train}
feeddict_test = {x: x_test, y: y_test}

### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    train_loss, test_loss = [], []
    for step in range(500):
        loss_train, _ = sess.run([loss, train], feed_dict=feeddict_train)
        train_loss.append(loss_train)

        # under the same tensorflow graph (in the session), use another feed dictionary 
        loss_test = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feeddict_test)
        test_loss.append(loss_test)

plt.plot(train_loss, 'r', label='train_loss')
plt.plot(test_loss, 'b', label='test_loss')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

here in this command `loss_test = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feeddict_test)`, the whole inputs `feeddict_test` will be 
taken and trained. what's about if I want to take it into two groups each groub contain only 2 items out of the available 
4, and then test them indpendentaly and contencate the outputs, is that possible ??

How can I do that? could you please help me in doing that if possible?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways your question can be interpreted due to the inaccuracy of your question.

**First interpretation:**
If what you're asking is that if your neural network receives an **input** vector of size 256 and **outputs** a vector of size 256, then the answer is no, you can't input a part of the vector as input and expect it to work.

**Second interpretation:**
If what you're asking is that if you have 256 **data** (each data is an n-sized vector) and you want to train the network by inputting the first 16, then the second 16, and so on until the 16th 16, yes it is very much possible. Based on the example code you've given, all you need to do is make a for loop that loops 2 times (because in your example, there are 4 data and you want to input them in a group of 2) and,

Change these lines of code:

```
for step in range(500):
        loss_train, _ = sess.run([loss, train], feed_dict=feeddict_train)`
```

to

```
for step in range(500):
        temp_list = [] #an empty list
        for i in range(0,4,2):
               loss_train, _ = sess.run([loss, train], feed_dict={x:x_train[i:i+2], y:y_train[i:i+2]}
               temp_list.append(loss_train) #append the loss of the network for each group of data.
```

These will allow the network to be trained with two groups of data independently and learn from them. You can simply make an empty list before the new **for loop** and concatenate the outputs in it.

Hope this helps. Do let me know if I understood your questions wrongly. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. First regarding the first interpretation, What's about if the neural network receives an input vector of size 256 and outputs is a vector of size 16 where the input vector will be trained by groups and each group has 16 inputs.  is that possible?if so,  how can I do that ?  Secondly, regarding the second interpretation,  I got your point and I will use that explanation in future work too, but what you mean by making an empty list before the new for loop and concatenate the outputs in it? how to do that? sorry I'm newbie in python I'm trying to understand it

Comment: Regarding the first interpretation, what I meant was that if your input vector should be 256 into the neural network, then you cannot input part of the vector. i.e. you try to input a vector sized 200. And for your new question on the first interpretation, that is what I answered originally in the second interpretation in the above post. I'll just point that out to you again. It is possible to train the network by grouping the input data (as long as each of them has a consistent length of vector that is accepted by the neural network.) You use the for loop like i mentioned previously.

Comment: As for the empty list, I'll update the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.   just the last question,I checked this article, https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/lwc.2017.2757490  at the last three lines of second page and start of third page, .. it describes the same idea  I asked, he is taking 16 inputs out of 256 neurons inputs, ....does that mean it's similar to your first interpretation or similar to my question? ...  thanks again

Comment: You're welcome :) I took a glance on the article and what I think is that, they're grouping 16 x 16 bits vectors to form a long 256 bits to input to the neural network. Probably the reason why there's 16 outputs in the end, 1 prediction for each group. This has nothing to do with either of my interpretations.

Comment: OK,  go it.  I will try to work on it and understand it with all details.

Comment: are you still there? I have faced an issue when implementing that solution you provided, it give me an error that : ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 1024) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 64)'        .... It's like it adds the dimension into the vector itself, if it doesn't take them by a size of 64.

Comment: Well your placeholder accepts a tensor of shape (?, 64), but you're feeding it a tensor of shape (64,1024). You either have to change the placeholder's shape or the input tensor's shape.

Comment: Yes, I solved it, I changed the placeholder's shape, I would like to ask you, is it possible to create that deep network using MATLAB? I'm so familiar with Matlab, and I tried searching about those kind of deep learning in matlab but I didn't get too many resources. do you have any idea if I can create those deep learning network using matlab or no?

Comment: Good to hear that :) Unfortunately, I would not be able to help you in this matter since I have never used Matlab at all.